# How do you add numbers in a while loop for c++?

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<iomanip>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // Declarations
    int firstNum = 0, secondNum = 0;

    cout << "This program will ask you for two numbers, and then output the even numbers between those two numbers" << endl;
    cout << "Please enter the lowest number: " << endl;
    cin >> firstNum;
    cout << "Please enter the highest number: " << endl;
    cin >> secondNum;

    if (firstNum % 2 != 0 && secondNum % 2 != 0)
    {
        while (firstNum <= secondNum)
        {
            if (firstNum % 2 != 0)
            {
                cout << firstNum << " ";
            }

            firstNum++;
        }
    }

    else if (firstNum % 2 == 0 && secondNum % 2 == 0)
    {
        while (firstNum <= secondNum)
        {
            if (firstNum % 2 == 0)
            {
                cout << firstNum << " ";
            }

            firstNum++;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I'm doing a coding exercise for c++, if the user inputs two odd numbers the program would then output all of the odd numbers between the first and second number (first number has to be smaller than the second). If both numbers are even then the program will out put the sum of the even numbers between the first and second (again the first has to be the smallest). My problem is that I do not know how to add the numbers together, I only know how to print either the even or odd numbers between them.

An example:

- first number = 4
- second number = 36
- output = 340

how do you add the even numbers between them?

Comment: also ignore the first cout message I forgot to get rid of that, it's not really needed.

Comment: Use a `int sum = 0;`, and instead of the `cout` do `sum+=firstNum;`

Answer (score 0):

You could have a variable that stores the result. For example

```cpp
else if (firstNum % 2 == 0 && secondNum % 2 == 0)
{
    int sum = 0; // store the sum of all even numbers
    while (firstNum <= secondNum)
    {
        sum += firstNum; // adding the number to the sum
        firstNum += 2; // increment by 2 would skip all the odd numbers
    }

    cout << sum << endl;
}
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: My code still does not work, it gives me a really big number. My code is in the link below.

Answer (score 0):

*`My problem is that I do not know how to add the numbers together`*  - If that is the exact question and assuming `start` and `end` are the start and end numbers you can do this to get the sum of all numbers between `start` and `end`

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = start; i <= end; i++  )
{
       sum += i;
}   
std::cout << "Sum of numbers between " << start << " and end " << end << " is " << sum ;
```

to get the sum of all even numbers in that range

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = start; i <= end; i++  )
{
    if ( i%2 == 0 ) // even
        sum += i;
}   
std::cout << "Sum of even numbers between " << start << " and end " << end << " is " << sum ;
```

I see you wanted it using `while loop` in which case

```
int sum = 0;
while ( start <= end  )
{
    sum += start;
    ++start;
}
```